# Bash -c with Java Process API

Tags: java, linux

I've been messing about with the java process API and ran into the following case:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        var command = "echo foo";
        System.out.println(command);
        run(command);

        command = "bash -c 'echo bar'";
        System.out.println(command);
        run(command);
    }

    public static void run(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        var br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        br.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Why does `bar` not print? I've also tried other commands like `systemctl poweroff` and `mkdir`, but none seem to execute. I've also experimented with `nohup`, which works on its own but not with `bash -c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call [exec(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)), which in turn calls [exec(String,String,File)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,java.lang.String%5B%5D,java.io.File)), which in turn uses a [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to chop the command line passed as a single string into an argument list, and then calls [exec(String[],String,File)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D,java.lang.String%5B%5D,java.io.File)).

However, that tokenizer just chops at spaces (it doesn't know that it's working with a command line or what shell would be involved). That means you end up with these tokens as the command: `bash`, `-c`, `'echo`, `foo'` --- note the single quotes; `Runtime.exec` does not involve a shell to handle quotes (or variable substitution or such).

bash then complains about the `'echo`, but you don't see that cause you only print the child process' `stdout`, but not `stderr`. Add code like this to `run`:

```java
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
System.out.println("stderr:");
br.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
```

This gets me:

```
stderr:
bar': -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bar': -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Now if you remove the single quotes from the call, you just get a single empty line because `bash -c` expects only one argument to run, which here is the `echo`, which prints a new line.

To fix this, you need to call the `exec` version that takes a `String[]` directly so that you control what is one argument:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        run("echo", "foo");
        run("bash", "-c", "echo bar");
    }

    public static void run(String... command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        var br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("stdout:");
        br.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
 
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        System.out.println("stderr:");
        br.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: You answer does not consume both streams simultaneously so won't work properly for every sub-process - try with `run("bash", "-c", "for i in {1..9999} ; do echo Hello STDERR $i 1>&2 ; done ; echo Hello STDOUT");`. You might need to vary the size of the loop for some platforms.

Comment: @DuncG True. This requirement was not in the question. The question was why the 2nd command doesn't seem to run at all. It's just the basics for running a command, and you are correct that this doesn't handle lots of output well.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use something higher level like the standard [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class or the [exec library from Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) instead, as they have better support for building complicated commands to execute:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.exec.*;

public class ExecDemo {
    // Build and execute a command with Apache Commons Exec
    private static void demoApacheExec()
        throws IOException, ExecuteException {
        var cmd = new CommandLine("sh");
        cmd.addArgument("-c");
        cmd.addArgument("echo test 1", false);
        System.out.println("Command: " + cmd);

        var executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        executor.execute(cmd);
    }

    // Build and execute a command with ProcessBuilder
    private static void demoProcessBuilder()
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // Can also take a List<String> of arguments
        var pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "echo test 2").inheritIO();
        System.out.println("Command: " + pb.command());

        pb.start().waitFor();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            demoApacheExec();
            demoProcessBuilder();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error executing program: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing is making each argument its own separate thing instead of relying on trying to parse a single string like a shell would (A.C.E has a `CommandLine.parse()` function, but even it has issues with quoting; `addArgument` likes to put actual quotes around arguments with spaces in them when it doesn't actually need to unless you tell it not to.).